# How do you create a template with replaceable variables for JS/React?

Tags: templates, graphql, yaml, graphql-js

Context:

1. I want to create a GraphQL query **template** with different variables that I can replace with key/values from another dictionary
2. I want to give JS/React this template and dictionary and be able to replace the variables in the template with the corresponding values in the dictionary

How would you recommend I do this?

One idea is to represent the GraphQL templates as txt files and use JS string interpolation.

```
query {
  pets {
    ${some_replaceable_attribute}
    ${another_replaceable_attribute}
  }
}
```

And have JS do all the token replacements.

Do you have any other suggestions on how I should do this?

Thank you!